# extract array from string that is a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function

```
var myvar = '
    myname({    "country":{        "cities":[ {"id":"3", "population":"3700"},{"id":"5", "population":"3730"}]   } });';
```

So that `myvar` is a string.

How to get `citiesArr` array of `city` objects from `myvar`?

Comment: just an opinion, i see no [json](http://json.org/).

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There is no JSON in this post. `myvar` holds a string that appears to be some JS code. In that code you have a call to a function to which you are passing a JS object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it valid JSON first by removing `myname(` at beginning and `);` at the end, use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for that. After that parse the string using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method and get the data you want.

```js
var myvar = 'myname({    "country":{        "cities":[ {"id":"3", "population":"3700"},{"id":"5", "population":"3730"}]   } });';

console.log(JSON.parse(myvar.replace(/^\s*\w+\(|\);$/g, '')).country.cities);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not a json object, it contains a function, JSON is only a javascript object.

to get this you might need to use eval, although i dont recommend.

```js
var myvar = 'myname({    "country":{        "cities":[ {"id":"3", "population":"3700"},{"id":"5", "population":"3730"}]   } });';

function myname(jsonObj) {
  console.log(jsonObj)
}

eval(myvar); //will log the whole object.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your json to

var myvar = {    "country":{        "cities":[ {"id":"3", "population":"3700"},{"id":"5", "population":"3730"}]   } };

and you can get the cities as myvar.country["cities"]

Answer (score 1):

JSON is valid JavaScript, but not all valid JavaScript is [valid JSON](http://json.org/).

As Nina pointed out in comments on the question, the string you've pasted in your question might be valid JavaScript, but it is not valid JSON.

Once you've corrected that problem, you can [use this solution to parse your JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript):

```
var myvar = '{"country":{"cities":[{"id":"3", "population":"3700"},{"id":"5", "population":"3730"}]}}';
var theData = JSON.parse(myvar);
```

> How to get citiesArr array of city objects from myvar?

Once you've used `JSON.parse(...)` to get back an object, you can use it like you'd normally use an object:

```js
var myvar = '{"country":{"cities":[{"id":"3", "population":"3700"},{"id":"5", "population":"3730"}]}}';
var theData = JSON.parse(myvar);
var cities = theData.country.cities;
console.log(cities);
```

If you're not getting the string from a third party (like a file or a web server) then you may want to consider just building the object the normal way rather than trying to use strings of JSON at all:

```
var myvar = {"country":{"cities":[{"id":"3", "population":"3700"},{"id":"5", "population":"3730"}]}};
```